# Unity - Resizing one GameObject to match another

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I'm working on a project in Unity that involves regions that teleport any non-static object from one to the paired. That part's fine, but for convenience, I'm trying to write a part of the script that will resize one object if its pair is resized, such that they will always be of equal size. And so far it works - mostly. The only problem I encounter is when trying to resize through the Transform component - as in, typing in numbers in Inspector, or using the value sliders on X or Y or Z. The handles work fine. It's not a big deal, I suppose, but if I could figure out why this isn't working, so I can learn what to do in the future, I'd be very glad. Here's the code:

```
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class TransferRegion : MonoBehaviour {
    // Unrelated code...

    public bool scaleManuallyAltered {
        get; private set;
    }

    [SerializeField]
    private TransferRegion pair;

    private Vector3 scale;

    // Called whenever the scene is edited
    void Update () {
        if (scale != gameObject.transform.localScale) {
            scaleManuallyAltered = true;
            scale = gameObject.transform.localScale;
        }
        if (pair && scaleManuallyAltered && !pair.scaleManuallyAltered) {
            pair.transform.localScale = scale;
        }
    }

    // Called AFTER every Update call
    void LateUpdate () {
        scaleManuallyAltered = false;
    }

    // Unrelated code...
}
```

If anyone can see some major logical failure I'm making, I'd like to know. If my code's a bit hard to understand I can explain my logic flow a bit, too, I know I'm prone to making some confusing constructs.
Thanks folks.

Comment: What does your code do and what doesn't it do? How are you scaling if not through the `Transform`?

Comment: The code looks to see if the applied object has been resized, and if it has, it resizes the paired object. More precisely, if the GameObject's current scale is not the same as the previous recorded scale; in that case, it sets its `scaleManuallyAltered` flag to true and then resets the scale variable, then checks to see if the other GameObject has been resized as well; if it hasn't, it changes the scale on the pair to its current scale.

Comment: Oh, right. The code I'm looking at *almost* works. The key failure: it doesn't seem to enjoy accepting manual, type-in-the-number scale edits in the Transform component on one object or the other. And I'm not sure what you mean by "not scaling through Transform" -- because I think I *am*.

Comment: That question was about "The only problem I encounter is when trying to resize through the Transform component." It implies that you don't encounter problems when resizing without the Transform component. Your comments have clarified, your post is just misleading I think. Edit: that's much better, I'll take a deeper look when I have access to a Unity environment.

Comment: There, I think that probably clarifies better. This is probably just some silly failure on my part, but it just seems peculiar that it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one object to be the same scale as another, why not just simplify your code by setting the scale of the re sizing game object, directly to the scale of the game object it is based off of?  For example, this script re sizes an object to match the scale of its pair while in edit mode:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class tester : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform PairedTransform;

    void Update()
    {
        if (!Selection.Contains(gameObject))
        {
            gameObject.transform.localScale = PairedTransform.localScale;
        }
    }
}
```

I tested this on two cubes in my scene.  I was able to resizing using gizmos as well as manually typing in numbers to the transform edit fields in the inspector.

Edit: By taking advantage of `Selection` you can apply the scale change only to the object in the pair that is not selected in the hierarchy.  This way the pairs wont be competing with each other to re scale themselves.

Comment: Ooh, so close! That *almost* works. The problem is, it works *only one way*. Object A gets resized fine and Object B matches it, sure, but the problem is that if you try to resize B, it constantly references the script and resets itself to A's scale - which is exactly why I didn't take the easy route and had the convoluted system in the first place.

Comment: I did not think about scaling from both objects.  I have edited my answer to fix that issue!

Comment: I have never used Selection before! I never even thought it existed! Thanks much!!

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out.
I'm not sure *what* was wrong with my original code, but eventually I decided to slip into the realm of good old handy events:

```
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class TransferRegion : MonoBehaviour {
    //...
    [SerializeField]
    private UnityEvent rescaled;
    //...
    void Update() {
        if (scale != gameObject.transform.localScale) {
            scale = gameObject.transform.localScale;
            rescaled.Invoke();
        }
    }
    //...
    public void OnPairRescaled() {
        gameObject.transform.localScale = pair.transform.localScale;
        scale = gameObject.transform.localScale;
    }
}
```

And just set the OnPairRescaled event to be the listener for the paired object's `rescaled` event.

Ta-da!